# PictureBox in InputBox

Tags: c#, picturebox, inputbox

I want to put a PictureBox in an InputBox, I try in this way, but it doesn't work (the picture don't appears):

The original code from InputBox is this: http://www.csharp-examples.net/inputbox/
I just changed a bit.

**The code that include PictureBox from InputBox:**

```
public static DialogResult Show(string title, string luna_text, ref string luna_continut, string zi_text, ref string zi_continut, string ora_text, ref string ora_continut, string minut_text, ref string minut_continut, string mesaj, ref string imagine)

PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();

picture.ImageLocation = imagine;

picture.SetBounds(14, 60, 128, 128);

picture.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label1, textBox1, label2, textBox2, label3, textBox3, label4, textBox4, label5, picture, buttonOk });

imagine = picture.ImageLocation;
```

**The code that include PictureBox from Form1:**
*(The code is in a **private void** function)*

The image is add to **Resources** !!

```
string inputbox = "";
string imagine = "alarma.png";

inputbox = CeasAlarma.InputBoxAnuntareAlarma.Show("CEAS ALARMA", "Luna:", ref luna, "Zi:", ref zi, "Ora:", ref ora, "Minut:", ref minut, "------ Ai o alarma care sunt in acest moment ! ------", ref imagine).ToString();

if (inputbox == "Cancel" || inputbox == "OK")
   //will do something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will get your image into your `InputBox` make sure the size of the Form is large enough to show your image, you will also have to play with positioning. What I did was to add another parameter to the InputBox's New method to pass the image to your control. See how this works for you.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string value = "Document 1";

            if (Tmp.InputBox("New document", "New document name:", ref value, new Bitmap("Your Image Here") == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.Text = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Tmp  //Note new field called bitmap for passing your picture to the InputBox
    {
        public static DialogResult InputBox(string title, string promptText, ref string value, Bitmap image)
        {
            Form form = new Form();
            Label label = new Label();
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            Button buttonOk = new Button();
            Button buttonCancel = new Button();
            PictureBox picture = new PictureBox();


            form.Text = title;
            label.Text = promptText;
            textBox.Text = value;
            picture.Image = image;

            buttonOk.Text = "OK";
            buttonCancel.Text = "Cancel";
            buttonOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            buttonCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

            label.SetBounds(9, 20, 372, 13);
            textBox.SetBounds(12, 36, 372, 20);
            buttonOk.SetBounds(228, 72, 75, 23);
            buttonCancel.SetBounds(309, 72, 75, 23);
            picture.SetBounds(14, 60, 128, 128);

            label.AutoSize = true;
            textBox.Anchor = textBox.Anchor | AnchorStyles.Right;
            buttonOk.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
            buttonCancel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
            picture.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

            form.ClientSize = new Size(396, 400); //Changed size to see the image
            form.ClientSize = new Size(Math.Max(300, label.Right + 10), form.ClientSize.Height); //Changed position so you are not shrinking the available size after the controls are added
            form.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { label, textBox, buttonOk, buttonCancel, picture});
            form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            form.MinimizeBox = false;
            form.MaximizeBox = false;
            form.AcceptButton = buttonOk; 
            form.CancelButton = buttonCancel;

            DialogResult dialogResult = form.ShowDialog();
            value = textBox.Text;
            return dialogResult;
        }

    }
}
```

---

Just notice in your code that you are setting your ClientSize after you add your controls, therefore the image is showing up with a negative X location value. You can either make sure that the ClientSize is not less than the Form Size or set the ClientSize before you add your controls.  I made edits to the above example, please take a look at.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Parameter is not valid.

Comment: @user1534830 it is working on my computer I ran it before I posted. You need to verify that the parameters you are inputing are of the proper type. Try running this in a sample project not your main one. I am playing with it now because the smaller images are showing up outside the bounds of the form

Comment: My image is add to Resources and I add new Bitmap("alarma.png")
And my image have the dimensions 128 x 128 !

Comment: I creat a new project, and I add the code, the image to Resources and new Bitmap("alarma.png") for if where you have new Bitmap("Your Image Here"). I have the same error. I think that the program don't find the image.

Comment: @user1534830 I am using an Image from resources also and it is working, My example is self contained, play with it in a seperate project.

Comment: I found the problem, the problem is that the application don't found the image, I need to add Bitmap(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\PROGRAMARI\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Resources\alarma.png"). I need to add somehow the image in application, if I will give my application to a friend, not need to give him the image to.

Comment: @user1534830s if you added your image from the project properties resources. you can access it by `Properties.Resources.YourImageName`. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy.aspx) on how to add.

Comment: I try new Bitmap(@"Properties.Resources.alarma.png"), don't work !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14589/discussion-between-mark-hall-and-user1534830)

Answer (score 1):

try with this code in order to build your pictureBox

```
picture.Width = 100;

picture.Height = 100;//just an example

Bitmap image = new Bitmap("alarma.png");

picture.Image = (Image)image;

picture.SetBounds(14, 60, 128, 128);

picture.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;


form.Controls.AddRange(.....);
```